# Save drawn graphic to image (error)

Tags: vb.net

I got this error when I am trying to save the drawn graphics as image.
The image is successfully saved, but the error appear, and said "FileNotFound"

this is paint method (when form load, automatically drawing the graphics)

```
Private Sub Pictprev2_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Pictprev2.Paint
    Dim a As String = amplop.noSer.Text
    Dim b As String = amplop.nmpsrt.Text
    Dim C As String = amplop.ComboCluster.Text
    Dim d As String = amplop.ComboTraining.Text
    Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("Certificate Envelope Background - blank.jpg")
    Dim pfc As New PrivateFontCollection()
    pfc.AddFontFile("Amplop.ttf")
    Dim font1 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 11, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim font2 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 18, FontStyle.Underline)
    Dim font3 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 11, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim format As New StringFormat
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    e.Graphics.DrawString("No. " & a, font1, Brushes.Black, 688, 408, format)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(b, font2, Brushes.Black, 688, 423, format)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(C & " | " & d, font3, Brushes.Black, 688, 448, format)
End Sub
```

the error in the line of 
`Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("Certificate Envelope Background - blank.jpg")`

the click method is like this

```
Private Sub SameAsImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SameAsImageToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim a As String = amplop.noSer.Text
    Dim b As String = amplop.nmpsrt.Text
    Dim C As String = amplop.ComboCluster.Text
    Dim d As String = amplop.ComboTraining.Text
    Dim pfc As New PrivateFontCollection()
    pfc.AddFontFile("Amplop.ttf")
    Dim font1 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 14, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim font2 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 25, FontStyle.Underline)
    Dim font3 As New Font(pfc.Families(0), 14, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim format As New StringFormat
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    Dim jpg As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("Certificate Envelope Background - blank.jpg")
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(jpg)
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    g.DrawString("No. " & a, font1, Brushes.Black, 688 * 5, 421 * 5, format)
    g.DrawString(b, font2, Brushes.Black, 688 * 5, 432 * 5, format)
    g.DrawString(C & " | " & d, font3, Brushes.Black, 688 * 5, 453 * 5, format)
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim paths As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        PictureBox1.Image = jpg
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(paths & ".jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End If
End Sub
```

there are two things I don't know,
 1. Why the error is located in the paint method not in the click method?
 2. How to fix that?

please help 
sorry for my bad English

Thanks :)

Comment: Two things. (1) Are you sure the click method does not give an error? Both code snippets look the same to me. (2) Specifying the full path to the image you are using (`Certificate Envelope Background - blank.jpg`) can fix your error.

Comment: Ah I got it, perhaps save image method will change the path of the image. so i make the function to make the path back to the original path, Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. +1 for learning how to solve your problem.